# Object return type in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

During angular [Tour of Heroes](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aygnjyjgero?file=src%2Fapp%2Fin-memory-data.service.ts) turorial, I didn't understand this way of object return.

```
 createDb() {
 const heroes = [
   { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
   { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
   { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
   { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
   { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
   { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
   { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
   { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
   { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
   { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
 ];
 return {heroes}; // <-- this line
}
```

Does it mean `return {'heroes': heroes}` ?
What is called this syntax ?

Comment: yes, it is a shortcut to `{'heroes': heroes}`

Comment: out put will {'heroes': heroes}

Comment: With this syntax you're returning an Object. Not you mentioned there, like this:
{heroes: heroes}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean `{'heroes': heroes}` ?

Yes.

> What is called this syntax ?

*Object Property Value Shorthand*

https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/